# Raw body request with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to do the following request with retrofit2:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://myserver.com/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"param1": "1234", "param2": "5678"}'
```

but the server (which I don't have control on) is complaining that the param1 param is missing.

How this curl request would look like on retrofit2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *[**retrofit**](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library (v2.0)* for android,

you can create **raw request** body for your API in **POST** type, something like:

```
@POST("token")
public void yourApiName(@Body YourPOJO pojo);
```

*YourPOJO.java*

```
public class YourPOJO{
    // Your params here, use @Serialized name if using with Gson
    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    // Getters & setters here. 
}
```